# Unable add ValueAxis property to Amchart stock graph

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to add title to the first graph in a multiple stock graphs list.
But it doesn't show up.
Here is the code:

```
stockGraphs: [{
            id: "g1",
            valueField: "value",
            comparable: true,
            bullet: "round",
            valueAxis: [
            {
             title: "t1"
            }]
}]
```

Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZaZZpy)

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the [documentation](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#valueAxis), the `valueAxis` property takes an id or a *reference* to the valueAxis object. You're trying to assign an array, which is way off.

You need to add an `id` to the `valueAxes` array inside your panel in your demo, then set the `valueAxis` property to the id as a string:

```
  valueAxes: [
    {
      id: "t1",
      title: "t1",
      maximum: 3000
    },{
      id: "t2",
      title: "t1",
      position: "right",
      maximum: 3000
    }
  ],
  stockGraphs: [
    {
      id: "g1",
      valueField: "value",
      comparable: true,
      bullet: "round",
      valueAxis: "t1"
    },{
      id: "g2",
      valueField: "value2dataset1",
      comparable: true,
      bullet: "round",
      valueAxis: "t2"
    }
  ],
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/c4396ec1f9e634d8211a2c4c2217dc24/)

I added a second value axis as assigning a value axis to a graph only helps if you need to display multiple value axes in a panel as all graphs will use the first value axis by default if it is not assigned.